# how to read a string input class <input class> in selenium c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to read the value (string) of input class  in selenium.

this is the HTML code of the element I want to read:

```
<input class="form-control" id="GroupName" maxlength="50" name="GroupName" required="required" type="text" value="MirnaTestGroup">
```

how to read "MirnaTestGroup"?
I used this code in selenium but the returned string is null:

```
expectedGroupName = Global.WebDriverHandle.FindElement(By.XPath("PATH")).Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution, and it worked:

```
expectedGroupName = Global.WebDriverHandle.FindElement(By.XPath("PATH")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as well..

```
        // Target element where tag type = input , attribute name = id , value = GroupName
        string AttributeSelector = "input[id= 'GroupName']";
        // search the element
        var elmTemp = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(AttributeSelector));
        // Then extract string value that inside attribute name , value
        string extractString = elmTemp.GetAttribute("value");
```